# wget not downloading files recursively

Tags: directory, wget, recursive

I saw some of the posts on this website about how to download files from a directory recursively. So, I executed the following line:

```
wget -r -nH --cut-dirs=3 -A '*.bz2' -np http://www.xfce.org/archive/xfce-4.6.2/src/
```

It only downloads the index page and then deletes it automatically.

Output:

```
--2016-07-01 16:56:02--  http://www.xfce.org/archive/xfce-4.6.2/src/
Resolving www.xfce.org (www.xfce.org)... 138.48.2.103
Connecting to www.xfce.org (www.xfce.org)|138.48.2.103|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://archive.xfce.org/xfce/4.6.2/src/ [following]
--2016-07-01 16:56:17--  http://archive.xfce.org/xfce/4.6.2/src/
Resolving archive.xfce.org (archive.xfce.org)... 138.48.2.107
Connecting to archive.xfce.org (archive.xfce.org)|138.48.2.107|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’

index.html                                [ <=>                                                                      ]   8.05K  --.-KB/s   in 0.03s  

2016-07-01 16:56:23 (247 KB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [8239]

Removing index.html since it should be rejected.

FINISHED --2016-07-01 16:56:23--
Total wall clock time: 21s
Downloaded: 1 files, 8.0K in 0.03s (247 KB/s)
```

The web-directory contains a lot of `tar.bz2` files. Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

My wget version is `1.16.3`

Comment: try adding `--no-parent` option

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: It is still not working

Comment: do you want to exclude `index.html` ?

Comment: Yes. That would be good. But, before that I want to download the files from the directory

Comment: It is still outputting the same result as before.

Comment: are you able to connect to `http://www.xfce.org/archive/xfce-4.6.2/src/` and issue a command to list the files ?

Comment: Please try the command again with `-d` in the options, to show more about what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it is not trivial to get directory listing over http; I could get the `bz2` files using bellow:

```
wget -k -l 0 "http://archive.xfce.org/xfce/4.6.2/src/" -O index.html ; cat index.html | grep -o 'http://archive.xfce.org/xfce/4.6.2/src/[^"]*.bz2' | uniq -c | xargs wget
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you have done over here?

Comment: First download the index file of the page; pipe it to grep to fetch the `bz2` file names. Then uses another `wget` to fetch those files. Not very efficient but it works I think. Did you try it?

Comment: `sort` is not necessary and `uniq` is to avoid duplicates.

Comment: Yes, it worked.