# Wget: downloading files selectively and recursively?

Tags: wget, directory-structure, recursive, http, download

Question about `wget`, subfolder, and index.html.

Let's say I am inside "travels/" folder and this is in "website.com": "website.com/travels/".

Folder "travels/" contains a lot of files and other (sub)folders: "website.com/travels/list.doc" , "website.com/travels/cover.png" , "website.com/travels/[1990] America/" , "website.com/travels/[1994] Japan/", and so on...

How can I download solely all ".mov" and ".jpg" that resides in all the subfolders only? I don't want to pick files from "travels/" (e.g. not "website.com/travels/list.doc")

I found a `wget` command (on Unix&Linux Exchange, I don't remember what was the discussion) capable of downloading from subfolders only their "index.html", not others contents. Why download only index files?

Comment: Hi @T. Caio would you please correct your link. it seems not the correct one!

Comment: Hi @Goro, what link should I correct? Sorry, I'm not english-speaker and I'm quite new to Linux

Comment: In the question you said `Here on https://unix.stackexchange.com  ...` there is no question about `wget` in this link! you probably copy/paste the unix website link

Comment: So you would like to know how to download (only) images an videos from a website subfolders, is this correct?

Comment: @Goro Correct! The subfolders are more than one

Comment: please try below and let me know if you have additional questions ;-) I encourage you to read wget man https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Directory_002dBased-Limits very useful!

Comment: I'll try in a few hours. But from what I see your suggestion seems similar to the one I already try and that grabbed *only* the index.html files inside the subfolders

Comment: The flag `-A ` in the command means accept specific extensions. You can add the flag `-R` and a list of files extensions that you don't want to download e.g. *.html The flag `-l 1` means download from subdirectories in depth 1 from the parent folder, you can adjust the depth of the subfolders based on this flag

Comment: @Goro I'll let you know. See you later, thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This command will download only images and movies from a given website:

```
wget -nd -r -P /save/location -A jpeg,jpg,bmp,gif,png,mov "http://www.somedomain.com"
```

According to [wget man](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html):

```
-nd prevents the creation of a directory hierarchy (i.e. no directories).

-r enables recursive retrieval. See Recursive Download for more information.

-P sets the directory prefix where all files and directories are saved to.

-A sets a whitelist for retrieving only certain file types. Strings and patterns are accepted, and both can be used in a comma separated list (as seen above). See Types of Files for more information.
```

If you would like to download subfolders you need to use the flag `--no-parent`, something similar to this command:

```
wget -r -l1 --no-parent -P /save/location -A jpeg,jpg,bmp,gif,png,mov "http://www.somedomain.com"

-r: recursive retrieving
-l1: sets the maximum recursion depth to be 1
--no-parent: does not ascend to the parent; only downloads from the specified subdirectory and downwards hierarchy
```

Regarding the index.html webpage. It will be excluded once the flag `-A` is included in the command `wget`, because this flag will force `wget` to download specific type of files, meaning if `html` is not included in the list of accepted files to be downloaded (i.e. flag `A`), then it will not be downloaded and `wget` will output in terminal the following message:

```
Removing /save/location/default.htm since it should be rejected.
```

`wget` can download specific type of files e.g. (jpg, jpeg, png, mov, avi, mpeg, .... etc) when those files are exist in the URL link provided to `wget` for example:

Let's say we would like to download .zip and .chd files from this [website](https://archive.org/download/MAME0.139_MAME2010_Reference_Set_ROMs_CHDs_Samples/roms/)

In this link there are folders and .zip files (scroll to the end). Now, let's say we would like to run this command:

```
wget -r --no-parent -P /save/location -A chd,zip "https://archive.org/download/MAME0.139_MAME2010_Reference_Set_ROMs_CHDs_Samples/roms/"
```

This command will download .zip files and at the same time it will create an empty folders for the .chd files.

In order to download the .chd files, we would need to extract the names of the empty folders, then convert those folder names to its actual URLs. Then, put all the URLs of interest in a text file `file.txt`, finally feed this text file to `wget`, as follows:

```
wget -r --no-parent -P /save/location -A chd,zip -i file.txt
```

The previous command will find all the chd files.

Comment: `wget -r -l2 --no-parent -P /my/local/path/ -A jpg https://website.com/remotefolder/` is NOT working (for my needs). `wget` "entered" in all subfolders, but for each one it only downloaded respective "index.html" files (removing them because rejected). It didn't even try to download further contents!

Comment: @Guru with your last try, `wget` keep continuously on entering in all the subfolders but the only thing it do is to (try) to download "index.html" (rejected), only that. Nothing more. Seems like `wget` is blind to what's inside in every subfolders...

Comment: @Guru  I tried omitting the `-A` option: only "index.html" is downloaded no other files (neither sub-subfolders). GNU Wget 1.19.5 on Arch Linux x86_64

Comment: `wget -r --no-parent -P /local/path -A chd https://archive.org/download/MAME0.139_MAME2010_Reference_Set_ROMs_CHDs_Samples/roms/`

Comment: your last command still is NOT working. Could you check if maybe the reason (for my case) is something related to?: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/293283/wget-not-downloading-files-recursively

Comment: I don't know how to proof to you that it is working. But I know that I got png files from bing. Also I tried www.google.com and I got images!

Comment: mmm... You tried my *exact* command? Maybe that website has some weird configs?

Comment: Try to add this flag `-erobots=off` after the flag `-r` and re run and let me know

Comment: with `-erobots=off` after the flag `-r`the behavior still remains the same. Keep "entering" inside each subfolder but the only thing `wget` see and try to download is solely "index.html"...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83499/discussion-between-t-caio-and-goro).

Comment: @ T. Caio Please see my edits. Let's chat!

Comment: Yes! Worked! I am left with empty "somename.zip" folders corresponding to the *.zip inside the parent. Then I also have all the subfolders that I need, each one with with its *.chd content! `wget -r --no-parent -P /local/path/ -A chd https://archive.org/download/MAME0.139_MAME2010_Reference_Set_ROMs_CHDs_Samples/roms/`